# Array Processing

Tags: java, arrays

Array Processing

Hi! I need to create a boolean method that processes two strings and returns if one is a subset of another. Example
if AAC is a subset of AAABBCK return true/

I currently have

```
    for (int i = 0; i < shorterArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < longerArray.length; j++) {
            if longerArray[j] == shorterArray[i] {
                count++
            }
        }
        if (count == shorterArray.length) {
            return true
        ) else {
            return fasle;
        }
    }
```

However this doesn't take into account the repetitions

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you supply some examples of input strings and the output you expect to get for them?

Comment: What helps processing arrays properly is **writing syntactically valid Java code**.

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: me thinks Bradley is confusing arrays with strings.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr me thinks Bradley is confusing Java with Javascript. Otherwise he'd have the proper semicolon placement.

Comment: Please improve your question by including the declaration of the two arrays.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'm not really sure that `fasle` is a Javascript keyword :-).

Comment: "return fasle;" will also not get you very far, neither in java nor in javascript.

Comment: The main problem is that it doesn't recognize repetitions in array classes

Answer (score 1):

```
return longerString.indexOf(shorterString) > -1;
```

Never mind, thanks to Joachim for correcting me on the definition of subset. Now I have to provide the correct answer.

```
public boolean isSubset(String subset, String superset)
{
    boolean[] used = new boolean[superset.length()];
    iLoop:
    for (int i = 0; i < subset.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < superset.length(); j++) {
            if (!used[j] && subset.charAt(i) == superset.charAt(j)) {
                used[j] = true;
                continue iLoop;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is not the definition ob subset. It is a substring existance where you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the built in methods within the String class :

`String input="your input string with substring";
CharSequence findMe="substring";
boolean retval = input.contains(findMe);`